# Program keeps looping without calling function

Tags: python, function

I am writing a program that asks two users boy or girl names and whether they like them or not. This is the beginning of the program and I created a function so if they don't input boy or girl, it asks them again so the program can properly run.

```
user_name_class= BabyNames()

print "Let's get started!"
print "Who will user1 be and who will user2 be?"

name_user1 = raw_input("User1 = ")
name_user2 = raw_input("User2 = ")

print user_name_class.baby_namer(raw_input("Do you want boy or girl names? \n").lower())

class BabyNames():

def baby_namer(self, gender): 
    self.gender = gender
    if 'b' not in gender or 'g' not in gender:
        return self.start_wrong_input()
    elif 'b' in gender:
        test = raw_input("What round are you on? (1-{}) \n".format(str(len(boy_rounds))))
        return boy(boy_rounds[test])
    elif 'g' in gender:
        test = raw_input("What round are you on? (1-{}) \n".format(str(len(girl_rounds))))
        return girl(girl_rounds[test])
    else:
        pass

def start_wrong_input(self):
    x = BabyNames()
    print "You need to put boy or girl to move on!"

    re_try = raw_input("Do you want boy or girl names? \n").lower()
    if 'g' in re_try:
        return x.baby_namer('girl')
    elif 'b' in re_try:
        return x.baby_namer('boy')      
    else:
        print "You need to put boy or girl to move on!"
```

I know creating the class probably wasn't necessary, but I just learned about them so I tried incorporating them into my code.
What is happening is at "Do you want boy or girl?" if you input anything else besides that, it properly calls the function and re-asks it but then when you put boy or girl, it loops and continues to asks the question without breaking. Why is this happening and let me know if I need to elaborate on anything else!(ps I'm a beginner so it may not be pythonic, but I'm working on it!)

Comment: Where are functions `boy()` and `girl()` ? Where are `girl_rounds` and `boy_rounds` ? Correct indentions. Why do you create `x = BabyNames()` inside class `BabyNames` ? Put class at the beginning of code - it will be more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `if 'b' not in gender and 'g' not in gender`, using or always puts you back to the `start_wrong_input` method because if gender is  `girl` `b` is not in `girl` and if  gender is  boy `g` is not in `boy` so `if 'b' not in gender or 'g' not in gender:`  will always evaluate to `True`

```
class BabyNames():
    def baby_namer(self, gender):
        if 'b' not in gender and 'g' not in gender:
            return self.start_wrong_input()
        elif 'b' in gender:
            test = raw_input("What round are you on? (1-{}) \n".format(str(len(boy_rounds))))
            return boy(boy_rounds[test])
        elif 'g' in gender:
            test = raw_input("What round are you on? (1-{}) \n".format(str(len(girl_rounds))))
            return girl(girl_rounds[test])
        else:
            pass

    def start_wrong_input(self):
        print "You need to put boy or girl to move on!"
        re_try = raw_input("Do you want boy or girl names? \n").lower()
        if 'g' in re_try:
            return self.baby_namer('girl') # use self.baby_namer, you don't need to use x = BabyNames()  
        elif 'b' in re_try:
            return self.baby_namer('boy')
        else:
            print "You need to put boy or girl to move on!"
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is in `baby_namer`:

```
if 'b' not in gender or 'g' not in gender:
```

You probably want a 'and' there, you fail if it is not a boy or if it is not a girl. You could try with entering the 'boyg' value...

Apart from that, you should not use recursive calls to make loops, it's difficult to read ! Use a proper `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You've create something that's called [*mutual recursion functions*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion)

function: `baby_namer()` calls `start_wrong_input()` and then `start_wrong_input()` calls back in return to `start_wrong_input()`. And you got yourself an infinite loop.